# Scala XML Omit Closing Tag

Tags: xml, scala, option-type

In order to generate valid XML closing tags must be provided in order to pass the type checker (yes, you can add a single element with a trailing slash like `<foo />` but generated xml node is `<foo ></foo>`)

For XHMTL this can cause problems, particularly with standalone tags like `br, img`, and in my current case, the much needed `<wbr>` tag.

Is there a way to omit the trailing tag, or is this not possible?

I'm building up XHTML using a `NodeBuffer` if that helps

Can't find any thread newer than 2011 that points remotely in this direction so I suspect not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, XHTML must be valid XML, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Stand-alone tags are, as you noted, indicated with the trailing slash (`<br/>`).

*How* that tag is specified (in code) or printed, `<br/>` or `<br></br>`, is simply a choice - it's still a *single node* without child elements.

Comment: yes, that's correct, just toString'd it and voila, single tag.  Play framework's raw Html wrapper must be doing some post-cleaning up work, great

Answer (score 1):

You can mark standalone XML tags like so:

```
<br />
```

instead of

```
<br>
```

This is valid in Scala, so you can write

```
val x = <br />
```

instead of

```
val x = <br><br/>
```

Note that the following will cause a compile-time error:

```
val x = <br>
```